# How does destructuring assignment evaluate the result in my case？

Tags: javascript

I have following javascript code,

```
op = [
  {busiCode:"001",
    busiName:"Order"
  },
  {busiCode:"002",
    busiName:"Plan"
  }
]

const [{ busiCode = '' } = {}] = op

console.log(busiCode)
```

It prints `001`, I would ask how javascript evaluate the reuslt in the above code,

Thanks!

Comment: Your code asks that the value of the property "busiCode" from the first object in the `op` array be assigned as the value of a new constant called `busiCode`. Is that the question?

Answer (score 4):

The source value is an array. Thus, in the `const` declaration, the first `[` says "look inside the array"

```
const [     // plz look in array
```

Then, in the source, the elements of the array (well, the first one at least), are objects. Thus in the declaration the first `{` means "in the first element of the array, treat it as an object and look inside".

```
const [{    // plz look in object at array[0]
```

Then, the identifier `busiCode` says that you want it to look for a property called "busiCode" in the object in the array, and that you want a local constant with that name ("busiCode") and the value of that property in that first object in the array.

```
const [{ busiCode    // plz get "busiCode" property
```

Then the `= ''` means "if you can't find `busiCode` as a property just give me an empty string".

```
const [{ busiCode = ''   // default to empty string if not found
```

Then the object "lookup" part is completed with `}`, and `= {}` means that if the original array has no first element, do all that stuff with a dummy empty object".

```
const [{ busiCode = '' } = {}   // give me at least an empty string
```

The pattern of the left side of the destructuring matches the general "shape" of the right-hand side.